# Disambiguate the [apk] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

```sh
/ # apk --help | grep coffee
This apk has coffee making abilities.
/ # apk fetch coffee
Go and fetch your own coffee.
```

The Alpine `apk` command has coffee-making abilities (via two easter eggs), while the Android packages obviously don't!

This said, both the Alpine Package Keeper (package manager for the Linux distribution called Alpine) and Android Packages are referenced as "apk".

Since the tag [apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apk) have long been used for Android, then what would be the proper naming for the Alpine apk one?

Should it be

- [alpine-apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpine-apk) kind of obvious, for disambiguation
- [apk-tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apk-tool) As described in their wiki

  > This page documents the [apk tool](https://git.alpinelinux.org/apk-tools/)

  <sub>*Source: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux_package_management*</sub>
- [apk-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apk-tools) since it is the name of the package containing the apk binary
  <sub>*Source: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=v3.12&name=apk-tools&arch=x86_64&repo=main*</sub>
- else?

For now, I only see a few of those question wrongly tagged [apk and alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpine+apk), so they should be fairly easy to retag, still.

Comment: Note that [tag:apktool] is an already existing tag for a separate tool.

Comment: @SuperStormer That likely needs its own burnination. I see very few on-topic questions with that tag, mostly are script kiddos trying to decompile code that isn't their own, and I have trouble understanding why would we want to help them, even if it was programming related (which the above aren't)

Answer (score 21):

Tags like [alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpine) are the [broken windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) of Stack Overflow. They look fine, because they're ostensibly about programming, but are they really?

[alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpine) appears to mostly be used for cases where someone has a Docker image built on Alpine Linux, and they are having trouble with it because it doesn't have a particular piece of software installed, and they don't know enough about Linux to install it themselves. That sort of question seems like a much better fit for Server Fault.

In a similar vein, questions about a package manager for Alpine Linux should **definitely** not be asked here, because installing software is absolutely not programming. (If you believe it is, then you need to explain to me how running setup.exe is programming.) You may be installing said software to do something programming-related, but that is still not programming.

Hence my preference would be to have no specific tag for Alpine Linux's package manager, and burninate and blacklist the [alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpine) tag, because as far as I can see the latter will be covered just as well (in fact, arguably better) by [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) combined with various other relevant tags like [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker).

Unfortunately, since it seems the prevailing opinion on Meta these days is "it gets to stay even if its relation to programming is more tenuous than a politician's word", I can guarantee the above will be shouted down. So these bad tags will remain and/or be created, and terrible non-programming-related questions that don't belong here will have said tags applied, and we'll all just go on pretending that we aren't actually trying to combine Stack Overflow and Server Fault.

As such, let's go ahead and do our best to mitigate the fallout:

- Rename tag [alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpine) to [alpine-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpine-linux) to disambiguate (as the [alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpine) usage guidance currently notes, there's already Alpine.js, and I'm sure there will be other software projects similarly creatively named)
- Create tag [alpine-package-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpine-package-manager) for the package manager, with [alpine-apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpine-apk) as a synonym
- Add usage guidance to [apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apk) to suggest that people use [alpine-apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/alpine-apk) for questions that are about the latter and not Android

Comment: "they don't know enough about Linux to install it themselves. That sort of question seems like a much better fit for Server Fault" - no, Server Fault is explicitly for sysadmin professionals, not beginners.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Android and its APK file format existed long before Alpine Linux was even a blip in the eyes of the people who forked that distro. The fact that Alpine's maintainers chose to try to be clever by naming one of its tools after that well-known file format, instead of being truly clever and naming it something unambiguous, is their problem not ours. tl;dr [tag:apk] gets to stay as-is because it has precedence.

Comment: Personally, I don't equate being a beginner with being "lazy", "incompetent" or a "useless parasite'.

Comment: @Ian That wasn't what happened with the [tag:gas] tag. GNU assembler was a thing way before Google App Scripts, and thus had precedence, but it didn't get to stay as-is

Comment: @IanKemp I prefer Debian way to solve these ambiguities: none of them get the name :D