# The [nova] tag is about programming the Nova editor API, but is predominately used for Laravel Nova, should the editor use another tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [nova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nova) tag is about programming against the [Nova editor API](https://docs.nova.app), but is predominately used for tagging questions about Laravel Nova. Laravel Nova has its own tag, [laravel-nova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-nova), but people seem not to pay attention to use the right tag. So at the moment it is difficult to find questions about the editor via its tag. <del>As there seem to be much more questions about Laravel Nova than about the Nova editor,</del> should the editor use another tag like [nova-editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nova-editor), and [nova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nova) <del>become a synonym for [laravel-nova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-nova)</del> be removed? [I adopted the advice voiced in the comments, that removing the ambiguous name is the way to go]

Who would decide and put into effect such a change?

Comment: Seems better to just remove `nova` and use `nova-editor` and `laravel-nova`. Otherwise people will still misuse `nova`.

Comment: @VLAZ finally Debian's way is taking root on these discussions :D

Comment: @Braiam `debian$ su root`

Comment: @VLAZ `darkstar$ sudo su - root`

Comment: Good suggestion, @VLAZ. Can someone explain the Debian references? :)

Comment: Is Debian unofficial policy that if two packages share the same name, neither should get the name for their packages: not by seniority, nor popularity. I have been pretty vocal in these disambiguation request that SO is shooting itself in the foot by using popularity as metric of which meaning should an ambiguous tag have, rather than removing ambiguity.

Comment: @MartinW the debian package system uses simple names not unlike the tag system here. In case of products that share a name the package might be ambiguous. For example, installing "nova" might be the Nova Editor with whatever it requires or PHP and Laravel Nova. When such a clash arises, the people responsible for the repo management tend to remove the simple ambiguous package name, so users need to be more explicit in which one they want. So, splitting into "nova-editor" and "laravel-nova" is the usual strategy.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the Debian reference. I adapted my question.

Comment: @Braiam Would you feel any differently about the Android APK format vs Alpine apk tool case, where one is *wildly* more popular than the other?

Comment: @IanKemp [nope](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404178/disambiguate-the-apk-tag?#comment817774_404180)

Comment: Debian does occasionally go by popularity, i remember the one case when the `git` package name was replaced by the much more popular version control system.

Comment: @Braiam I saw that comment but I wasn't sure how much it was in jest, or not.

Comment: Did someone already go through and fixup all the questions tagged as [nova] when they should've been [laravel-nova]? The reason I ask is because when I checked [nova], it only had 7 questions, 5 of which were intended to be [openstack-nova] (which I've fixed). So currently [nova] has a grand total of two on-topic questions.

Comment: Right now there are a grand total of two (2) questions in [nova], one of which should probably be closed. I can't think of a more appropriate time for a mod to rename the tag to [nova-editor]. MODS PLZ.

Comment: @IanKemp with only 2 questions left do we need a mod at all?  Just retag the questions yourself, and then copy the tag wiki/etc from the old tag to the new tag.  The old tag will get cleaned up in time via a roomba.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström git-core was changed in 2010 to git, in case someone wants to see [the history](https://repo.or.cz/git/debian.git/blob/HEAD:/debian/git.NEWS#l66)

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Didn't think about doing it that way. Done. Have updated [nova] description and guidance to "DO NOT USE", all that is left is for a mod to nuke it.

Comment: @IanKemp tags without any questions will just disappear automatically without anyone's intervention :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this has now been carried out by the community, and the [nova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nova) tag is gone, so I'm marking this request as completed.

(I'm a bit uncomfortable with that, by the way. **When these posts get into Hot Meta Questions, the idea is that people will discuss it and post answers for or against, not that they'll start carrying out the burnination on their own.**)

Comment: "Who would decide and put into effect such a change?” was also part of my question. Can you explain what the intended workflow is for such a situation? I did not myself change any posts.

Comment: @MartinW You did nothing wrong. Your question was fine. I was not accusing you of changing any posts. Unfortunately, others did not follow the rules, and instead of simply answering your question, they inappropriately took matters into their own hands and manually removed the tag.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not aware of any guidance on retagging, particularly the necessity of having the community reach a consensus thereon. While [tag:nova] was burninated by the retagging I did, that was a side-effect not an intention.

Comment: @IanKemp Retagging a large number of questions is literally the definition of "burnination", so your feigning ignorance is not very compelling to me. The tag was only brought to your attention via this Meta question. Your decision to remove the tag was a direct result of this proposal, which was to burninate the tag.