# Should we add "DO NOT USE" to tags that are too large to be burninated?

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

Currently there is no sane way to burninate tags with large numbers of questions, because the burnination system (I use that word lightly) is entirely manual and incredibly painful, mostly because SE Inc. hates us.

But can we not at least (try to) discourage people from using tags that have been identified as "should be burninated at some mythical time in the future when SE Inc. pulls its thumb out", perhaps by editing their guidance to be prefaced with "DO NOT USE"?

In essence, the burnination process would change to work like this:

- Burnination proposal posted on Meta
- People vote on the merits of the request, **ignoring the number of questions currently in the tag**
- If the proposal is accepted by the community:

  - If the tag has a sufficiently small number of questions (**this number to be determined**), the current burnination process is executed
  - Else the tag guidance is simply edited **by the person proposing the burnination** to include "DO NOT USE"

Yes, I know that expecting most of the new users of Stack Overflow nowadays to be capable of basic literacy is a tall order, but this is at least better than doing nothing.

Comment: I would prefer that we reform the current burnination process.  It's so bureaucratic and overwrought that it's impractical except for the smallest cases, where it's not needed anyway.

Comment: The `web` tag currently says "Do not use this tag". I edit it out of about 5-10 questions a day. It just does not work.

Comment: That said, the "DO NOT USE" moniker is routinely ignored by new users, and since it's not enforceable ...

Comment: I suggest the following: **_DO NOT USE_**, but it's unlikely anyone will listen to it. we might as well keep it in case one user sees it and obeys it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Or at least, put the same process for tag creation. It's trivial to create a tag, yet it's absurdly hard to remove it.

Comment: @Braiam: I don't think those two things are morally equivalent.  Yes, it's trivial to create a tag, but it's done one question at a time.  By the time someone notices that there is a problem with the tag, it has 1000 questions; and nobody is arguing that a single user should be able to unilaterally remove all 1000 instances.

Comment: This is answered by [Shog9's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386142). In summary, no, you definitely should not add this. One person should not have the privileges to decide when a tag should or should not be used, aside from the fact that this "guidance" serves little purpose.

Comment: @CodyGray I think Shog9 missed the point on that answer. The point of that question wasn't the "DO NOT USE" text; it was the "Lock the tag" part.

Comment: @CodyGray Did you miss the part where I **explicitly stated** that making such an edit would have to form part of a burnination request and approval thereof?

Comment: I probably stopped reading and caring after skimming the beginning and ending rude sentences. Reading now, I don't see much difference between your proposed burnination process and the current one. The major difference is that you claim the "sufficiently small number of questions" is yet to be determined, yet the actual process has arrived at a number.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree 100%, and this question actually started out as "the current burnination process is fundamentally flawed, how can we fix it?" But my experience with burnination on meta has been that people really, really don't want to entertain it because it "adds no value" and "there are other more important things"; and when they do deign to allow it, any suggestion that maybe, just maybe the stuff Shog wrote years ago, shouldn't be treated as gospel - is shot down. End result, nothing gets done, nothing gets better, the cesspool just gets deeper.

Comment: @CodyGray Where is that number documented?

Comment: ["If you have authoritative knowledge of all technologies relevant to the tag, have conferred with at least one other trusted community member, and are dealing with a tag that has a small number of questions (< 50), then you can go ahead and remove it yourself or with a little ad hoc help."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think you are confused. It's about the effort required to create (a single 1.5k(?)) and remove (several 2k+) a tag that are very suboptimal. It's the difference between O(1) and O(n). There's no morality there. Then we add the wrench that is the "burnination process"... that just makes more work unnecessarily for something that is already difficult. That's why I propose at least put the wrench also in tag creation. Someone has to demonstrate that the tag they are creating doesn't meet any of the criteria of removal.

Comment: @braiam: Apparently I misunderstood your use of "tag creation" to mean the actual creation of a tag, which happens during its first use.  The creator of such a tag has a minimum rep requirement.  There must still be thousands of monkeys adding that tag so created to their questions for it to become a potential problem.  Despite the rep requirement, I wouldn't be opposed to adding a little friction to the process of creating a new tag.

Answer (score -7):

You know... [this already happened.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404454/792066) By this I mean working without the whole paraphernalia of the burnination process. If we embroiled ourselfs in the minutiae of the process... it would never have been done. It was done in more or less than 48 hours. I don't know how many questions it took, or how many users, but it demonstrated that it is *effective* and that's exactly what the process isn't.

Flipping the side of the process to tag creation, as a means of "tag approvals"... I think you will see how not having any vetting makes it trivial, since it doesn't have any of that. Heck, even the meta post asking for a tag to be created are usually promptly rejected or created in manner of minutes, by adding the tag to a single question. It's interesting that tag removal, which is inherently more difficult, by the number of questions involved, doesn't even get that timely resolution that creation does.

In summary, yes, the burnination process was trying to protect things from being permanently destroyed (they are not, since they are still on the revision history), but the solution to that is not to introduce more friction, but looking for a safe mechanism in which impacts are minimized (see argument to reduce the amount of close votes).

Comment: `You know... this already happened` -- Yeah, and according to a moderator, *without consulting the community first, as is supposedly required by this process.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey which is why the process is fundamentally flawed ;). If nothing is broken despite that requirement not fulfilled... why it is there?

Comment: What's broken is trust. I have no way to verify whether or not anything is broken, because you deleted it all. Follow this "advice" at your own risk. If you are caught embarking on a tag removal crusade like this, in violation of established site policies, your account may be suspended without warning.

Comment: @Braiam The requirement for discussion on Meta is there because individuals eventually, invariably get it wrong and can cause considerable damage if they just choose to start burning tags which they personally don't like without discussing it with others in the community at large. The [**requirement** that the process be followed is backed/imposed by Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356963/tag-removals-must-be-discussed-and-documented-on-meta), and includes a requirement to discuss the burnination on Meta for all but tags with a small number of questions.

Comment: The process is flawed, not because it requires community consensus, but because it requires *fixing everything else about each post before the tag can be individually removed.*  That's just too much overhead; it's not necessary, in my opinion, to overhaul every post in a tag just to remove a bad tag from the system.

Comment: @CodyGray no, nothing is ever deleted on SE. Haven't you seen it with moderation powers? Nothing is ever deleted. Really. Next week, I can easily search all questions that were edited and show a list, if I really want. So... again, trust in doing what? Why is  necessary? Just because "that's how it's done", doesn't mean that we can't improve it, or that it's actually bad as it is.

Comment: @Makyen by that assumption Shog is also wrong, because he is an "individual". SE has backtracked many things in the past, like Documentation, 5 close votes, etc. The fact that SE backed it, isn't because it's good. BTW, SO is the only site that use that process.

Comment: @RobertHarvey again with that community consensus... let me ask you, do you see anyone expressing disapproval in the question I linked? Ask a moderator in case there are deleted comments. I only see a question that was featured for at least 2 days, got plenty of "community support" in favor and was executed promptly.  That's how the burnination process should work: effective and without wasting everyone time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey also, the only reason why it requires fixing everything with the post is because it was meant for "tags which questions are invariably no bueno for SE". Why the process I linked didn't require that thing? Because it was disambiguation. Yes, the original tag wouldn't exist, but 2 more would be created. Trying to shoehorn the "process" into every tag deletion obviously would put off several members.